# Is * a group on the nonzero real numbers with a*b=a/b?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

The question states, Let *G* be the group of nonzero real numbers and let * be defined on *G* as *a*b=a/b*. Is *G* a group under *?

Would it then suffice to say that *G* is not a group because there is no unique identity such that *a*e=e*a=a*? Is there some other form of proof I should utilize? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works. You could also say $a/(b/c)$ vs $(a/b)/c$ for the lack of associativity.

Comment: It'd probably be better to give a specific example of failure, for example $2/(2/2)$ vs $(2/2)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. If we take an element from $G$, say $3$, then in order for identity to exist, we need to have 
$$\frac{e}{3} = \frac{3}{e} = 3$$
which has no solution because $\frac{e}{3} = 3 \implies e = 9$ however, $\frac{3}{e} = 3 \implies e = 1$, meaning that this equation system has no solution. Therefore $G$ has no identity element, so $G$ is not a group.